# Postgres copy with strings enclosed in quotes

Tags: postgresql

I have a tab delimited file I am trying to import into Postgres. It looks like this -

```
"ID"            "NBR"   
"101931126593"  "3"
```

I can successfully import this file using this command -

`\copy service from test.txt with delimiter E'\t' null as 'NULL';`

However, this is not omitting the quotes. For example, I want ID to be `101931126593` and not `"101931126593"`.

I have tried this so far, but it still does not import it without the quotes -

`\copy service from test.txt with CSV delimiter E'\t' QUOTE E'\b' null as 'NULL';`

Comment: Why are telling it that the quote character is a backspace?  That is not what your quote character is.

Answer (score 0):

`"` is the default quoting character anyway:

```
\copy service FROM 'test.txt' (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E'\t', NULL 'NULL')
```